# Setting token price on a Dex

Tags: tokens, decentralized-exchange, defi

There are various opinions and parameters when it comes to the setting of a token price.

What are the best practices when setting the token price on a Dex?

Answer (score 2):

Prices are set by the market. The best practice is to set the price to its fair value on the market.

If there is no market yet, you have to evaluate it. This is basically what investment banks will do before a stock IPO. It's very hard to do and their army of finance professionals often screw up anyways.

All in all, it is not an Ethereum question, but an economy question.